# How to calculate profit in percents?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple question. I have 2 variables a & b.
A is the money I get from a customer. B is the money I will pay to carrier.

So If i have 1000 from customer and I have paid 800 to carrier my profit will be 200 dollars (20%).

What's the formula in javascript?

Comment: Will be the same as in math

Comment: Can you provide the formula please?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. You're not learning anything if you haven't attempted it and seek full working solutions.

Comment: I tried:

let a = this.custFlatRate;
      let b = this.carrFlatRate;
      return ((a - b) / ((a + b) / 2)) * 100;

So a was 1000 and b was 500 the result is 0.09995002498750624% Profit

Answer (score 2):

Profit_percent = (gained-taxes) / gained * 100
Then just make it a string and add %.

```
var percent = (a-b)/a*100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
`var p=(a-b)*100/a`
Where p is the profit percent

Comment: Yeah I just missed that, Sorry!